# Iterative binary tree inorder traversal python

Tags: python, iteration, binary-tree

In [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/discuss/960715/Python-iterative) LeetCode Q/A an answer w/o any inline comments demonstrates how to accomplish **iterative** in-order binary tree traversal.

```py
class Solution:
    def inorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
        traversal = []

        node = root
        stack = []
        while node or stack:
            if node:
                stack.append(node)
                node = node.left
            else:
                node = stack.pop()
                traversal.append(node.val)
                node = node.right
                
        return traversal
```

Why does this work? I'm primarily confused by the `if node` statement, which always moves to the left child. The else statement must satisfy the conditions that node does not exist but stack does exist, and this is really perplexing to me.

I'd like to understand it such that I could tweak code to perform pre or post order traversal but not understanding why this code functions, that's a bride too far.

Comment: Just take a piece of paper and a small example tree and work it out on paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of every iteration of the loop, `node` represents the root of a subtree that has not yet been visited (at all).

By definition of "in-order traversal", we should first traverse the left subtree of a node, before anything else. So that is why -- when we have the root of an unvisited subtree -- we should go *left*. At the same time, we take note of the this node, because at some point we will be ready with that left subtree, and then we must be able to find back this node and actually *visit* it. That is why we push the node on the stack before going left.

When the root of an unvisited subtree has no left child, then `node` will obviously become `None` and so in the next iteration we arrive in the `else` case. There we pop again the parent node from the stack. Now the first thing to do is *visit* that root (`append`), and after that we must visit its *right* subtree, which will be initiated in the next iteration of the loop.